# recursive call in nonrecursive statement

Tags: postgresql, recursion

this is the "solution" to a question from a course i am taking. but when i copied it into my postgrSQL 9.5.1 program, and it is riddled with errors.

```
CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW Ancestor AS
((SELECT parents.child AS Dec, parents.father AS Anc
FROM windsor.parents)
UNION
(SELECT parents.child AS Dec, parents.mother AS Anc
FROM windsor.parents)
UNION
(SELECT parents.Father AS Anc, Ancestor.Dec As Dec
FROM windsor.parents,Ancestor
WHERE parents.child = Ancestor.Anc)
UNION
(Select parents.mother AS Anc, Ancestor.Dec As Dec
FROM windsor.parents, Ancestor
WHERE parents.child = Ancestor.Anc))
```

It threw an error in line:1, with a syntaxerror for 'AS'. After looking into some declarations [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html) and trying some stuff, it seemed like changing it to

```
CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW Ancestor(Anc,Dec) AS
```

worked, but now it throws an error the first time i try to call Ancestor in a `FROM` command. the Error this time is:

```
Error: rekursiver Verweis auf Anfrage „ancestor“ darf nicht in ihrem nicht-rekursiven Teilausdruck erscheinen
SQL Status:42P19
```

or in my broken english:

```
recursive call for "ancestor" mustn't be in a non-recursive part
```

like i said this is not my code. it is a "solution" for a question from a course i am attending. i am trying to fix this answer but dont want to drift too far away from the original intent with this code.

cheers - Jacobus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that in your view definition, you have *two* different recursive clauses, while only one is admitted.

In the PostgreSQL [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createview.html) the recursive view is defined as following:

> `CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW name (columns) AS SELECT ...;`
> is equivalent to
>
> `CREATE VIEW name AS WITH RECURSIVE name (columns) AS (SELECT ...) SELECT columns FROM name;`
>
> A view column list must be specified for a recursive view.

(note that the last statement *require* that you use `CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW Ancestor(Anc,Dec)`)

Then, in the [page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html) about `WITH RECURSIVE`:

> If RECURSIVE is specified, it allows a SELECT subquery to reference itself by name. Such a subquery must have the form
>
> `non_recursive_term UNION [ ALL | DISTINCT ] recursive_term`
>
> where the recursive self-reference must appear on the right-hand side of the UNION. **Only one recursive self-reference is permitted per query.** (emphasis is mine).

So, you should change your query by using only a recursive subselect.

*Edit*

Here is a possible solution, with a small modification of the query published by @JacobusConradi in a comment below:

```
CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW ancestor(anc, dec) AS 
  SELECT  father AS anc, child AS dec
  FROM windsor.parents 
  WHERE father is not null
     UNION 
  SELECT  mother AS anc, child AS dec
  FROM windsor.parents 
  WHERE mother is not null
     UNION 
  SELECT anc, child AS dec
     FROM windsor.parents, ancestor
     WHERE dec = father OR dec = mother
```

The modification concerns: 1) the elimination of DISTINCT (we can assume that `child` is a primary key of the original table, and in any case the use of the `UNION` operator automatically eliminates duplicates), 2) the addition of a test for null values, otherwise in the result would appear tuples with null values for either `anc` or `dec`.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer :) from what i understood from your answer, is that 1st: the (Anc,Dec) IS requiered, which makes total sense to me. The second one didnt make sense to me initially, with the "recursive only AFTER the union call", but i think i understood it now. The problem is ONLY in the third union block. how would i work around that, especially with the "one call limit"?

Comment: To answer to your question, I should know the `parents` table, which, from your view, is not clear to me. It is `(child, father, mother)`? Then, what is `name`? Or it is (`name, child, father, mother)`? Then I don't undestand what is child.

Comment: i now see another mistake that i seem to have overlooked when asking this question. it is (child, father, mother) and name was supposed to be child too. the guy who designed this course had it named "name" in all his Powerpoint-show, but the files he shared had it named "child". i edited in the question.

Comment: @JacobusConradi, your solution is almost correct, you should eliminate tuples with null values (and remove the distinct). I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Renzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038592/1104979) pointed out, you've got two issues to work around:

- Only one recursive reference is allowed
- That recursive reference must appear in the last part of the `UNION`

The second restriction is easily addressed by combining the last two elements of the `UNION` into a subquery; instead of `A UNION B UNION C UNION D`, simply say `A UNION B UNION (C UNION D)`.

As for factoring out the recursive call to a single reference, this is pretty straightforward to do with a [common table expression (CTE)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), giving you something like this:

```
CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW Ancestor(Anc,Dec) AS
SELECT parents.child AS Dec, parents.father AS Anc
FROM windsor.parents
UNION
SELECT parents.child AS Dec, parents.mother AS Anc
FROM windsor.parents
UNION
(
  WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM Ancestor)
  SELECT parents.Father AS Anc, cte.Dec As Dec
  FROM windsor.parents, cte
  WHERE parents.child = cte.Anc
  UNION
  SELECT parents.Mother AS Anc, cte.Dec As Dec
  FROM windsor.parents, cte
  WHERE parents.child = cte.Anc
)
```

Comment: i am thankful for your answer, even tho i already solved it  with what Renzo told me. I am curious tho, because your recursive call is not after the last "union", or is it because the last union is not on the same level as the other? I just executed it, and it works well, but i dont understand why it does work with the syntax requirements from above

Comment: @Jacobus: Yes, it's because it's nested; the requirement is that the last *top-level* union contains the recursive term.